# Xamarin Forms app is crashing on funtouch OS and color OS in Android after launched

Tags: xamarin.forms, crash

Xamarin forms app is crashing on vivo Android phones those are operating by funtouch OS and color OS. I have tried to get the reason behind the crash but did not found anything yet. If, someone face this kind of issue, Please give me some of solution to resolve this.

I have tried to debug the problem on the android device but no luck yet. Below are the some screenshots of device details:

[Screenshot of one of device on which facing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqkLz.jpg) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KybEd.jpg)

Below is the json which received on sentry (hope this will be helpful to understand the problem):

{"event_id":"d3a14f9ea375456fb7042268bf26da9c","project":4504321653669888,"release":"com.tsi.ipay@2.2.9+57","dist":null,"platform":"csharp","message":"","datetime":"2022-12-15T06:58:49.619733Z","tags":[["cpu.model","MT6762V/WR"],["device","vivo 1901"],["environment","production"],["handled","no"],["level","error"],["mechanism","AppDomain.UnhandledException"],["os","Android 11"],["os.name","Android"],["runtime","Mono 6.12.0"],["runtime.name","Mono"],["release","com.tsi.ipay@2.2.9+57"]],"_metrics":{"bytes.ingested.event":9482,"bytes.stored.event":10684},"breadcrumbs":{"values":[{"timestamp":1671087523.203,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":null,"state":"Started"}},{"timestamp":1671087524.469,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":null,"state":"Resumed"}},{"timestamp":1671087525.42,"type":"info","category":"xamarin","level":"warning","data":{"issue":"Material needs to be registered on Android by calling FormsMaterial.Init() after the Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init method call.","logger":"Visual"}},{"timestamp":1671087526.193,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"popup":"ProcessingView","state":"appearing"}},{"timestamp":1671087526.634,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"Stopped"}},{"timestamp":1671087526.64,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"SaveInstanceState"}},{"timestamp":1671087526.645,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"Destroyed"}},{"timestamp":1671087526.673,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"Paused"}},{"timestamp":1671087526.675,"type":"session","category":"app.lifecycle","level":"info","message":"Pausing Sentry Session"},{"timestamp":1671087527.032,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"popup":"ProcessingView","state":"disappearing"}},{"timestamp":1671087527.466,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"Stopped"}},{"timestamp":1671087527.558,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"SaveInstanceState"}},{"timestamp":1671087528.868,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"Started"}},{"timestamp":1671087528.985,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"screen":"LoginPage","state":"Resumed"}},{"timestamp":1671087528.992,"type":"session","category":"app.lifecycle","level":"info","message":"Resuming Sentry Session"},{"timestamp":1671087529.116,"type":"navigation","category":"ui.lifecycle","level":"info","data":{"popup":"ProcessingView","state":"appearing"}},{"timestamp":1671087529.635,"type":"session","category":"app.lifecycle","level":"info","message":"Ending Sentry Session"}]},"contexts":{"Current Culture":{"calendar":"GregorianCalendar","display_name":"English (United States)","name":"en-US","type":"Current Culture"},"ThreadPool Info":{"available_completion_port_threads":200,"available_worker_threads":200,"max_completion_port_threads":200,"max_worker_threads":200,"min_completion_port_threads":8,"min_worker_threads":8,"type":"ThreadPool Info"},"app":{"app_start_time":"2022-12-20T02:41:07.506512+00:00","type":"app"},"device":{"model":"vivo 1901","brand":"vivo","screen_resolution":"1544x720","screen_density":2.0,"online":true,"simulator":false,"memory_size":3994288128,"free_memory":1182928896,"storage_size":7427833856,"boot_time":"2022-12-08T07:52:14.6011828+00:00","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","type":"device"},"os":{"name":"Android","version":"11","type":"os"},"runtime":{"name":"Mono","version":"6.12.0","raw_description":"Mono 6.12.0 (2020-02/a96bde9730e)","type":"runtime"}},"culprit":"","environment":"production","exception":{"values":[{"type":"Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException","value":"No view found for id 0x2f (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{97112ae} (76e149fc-19ce-41a0-979b-c1893d7eda70 id=0x2f)","module":"Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065","thread_id":1,"mechanism":{"type":"AppDomain.UnhandledException","handled":false}}]},"fingerprint":["{{ default }}"],"grouping_config":{"enhancements":"eJybzDRxY3J-bm5-npWRgaGlroGxrpHxBABcYgcZ","id":"newstyle:2019-10-29"},"hashes":["0a1736c5ae9bad56b6e497c577a455ec"],"key_id":"2798897","level":"error","logger":"","metadata":{"display_title_with_tree_label":false,"type":"Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException","value":"No view found for id 0x2f (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{97112ae} (76e149fc-19ce-41a0-979b-c1893d7eda70 id=0x2f)"},"modules":{"AEPS":"1.0.0.0","AEPS.Android":"1.0.0.0","AEPS.BAL":"1.0.0.0","AEPS.Models":"1.0.0.0","AutoMapper":"10.0.0.0","Cashfree.Forms.Payment.Gateway":"0.9.2.0","DocumentFormat.OpenXml":"2.18.0.0","FFImageLoading":"2.4.11.982","FFImageLoading.Forms":"2.4.11.982","FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform":"2.4.11.982","FFImageLoading.Platform":"2.4.11.982","FastAndroidCamera":"2.0.0.0","Forms9Patch":"1.0.0.0","Forms9Patch.Droid":"1.0.0.0","FormsGestures":"1.0.0.0","FormsGestures.Droid":"1.0.0.0","FormsViewGroup":"2.0.0.0","HighlightMarker":"3.0.11.0","HighlightMarker.Forms":"3.0.11.0","Java.Interop":"0.1.0.0","Microsoft.AppCenter":"0.0.0.0","Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics":"0.0.0.0","Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes":"0.0.0.0","Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Options":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions":"6.0.0.0","Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives":"6.0.0.0","MimeSharp":"1.0.0.0","Mono.Android":"0.0.0.0","Mono.Security":"2.0.5.0","Newtonsoft.Json":"13.0.0.0","P42.NumericalMethods":"1.0.0.0","P42.Utils":"1.0.0.0","P42.Utils.Droid":"1.0.0.0","PlayCore":"1.10.2.0","Plugin.ImageEdit":"1.0.0.0","Plugin.ImageEdit.Abstractions":"1.0.0.0","RazorBindingLibrary":"1.0.0.0","Sentry":"3.23.1.0","Sentry.Xamarin":"1.4.5.0","Sentry.Xamarin.Forms":"1.4.5.0","SkiaSharp":"2.80.0.0","SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg":"1.60.0.0","SkiaSharp.Views.Android":"2.80.0.0","SkiaSharp.Views.Forms":"2.80.0.0","System":"2.0.5.0","System.Collections.Immutable":"5.0.0.0","System.Core":"2.0.5.0","System.Data":"2.0.5.0","System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource":"6.0.0.0","System.Diagnostics.EventLog":"6.0.0.0","System.Drawing.Common":"4.0.0.0","System.IO.Compression":"2.0.5.0","System.IO.Packaging":"4.0.5.0","System.Net.Http":"4.0.0.0","System.Numerics":"2.0.5.0","System.Reflection.Metadata":"5.0.0.0","System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe":"6.0.0.0","System.Runtime.Serialization":"2.0.5.0","System.Security.Principal.Windows":"5.0.0.0","System.Text.Encodings.Web":"6.0.0.0","System.Text.Json":"6.0.0.0","System.Xml":"2.0.5.0","System.Xml.Linq":"2.0.5.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.CardView":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Core":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.CursorAdapter":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.CustomView":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.DrawerLayout":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.Core.UI":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.Loader":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.VersionedParcelable":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.AndroidX.ViewPager":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Essentials":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Firebase.Common":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Firebase.Encoders":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Firebase.Encoders.Proto":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Forms.Core":"2.0.0.0","Xamarin.Forms.Platform":"2.0.0.0","Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android":"2.0.0.0","Xamarin.Forms.Xaml":"2.0.0.0","Xamarin.Google.Android.DataTransport.TransportApi":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Google.Android.DataTransport.TransportBackendCct":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Google.Android.DataTransport.TransportRuntime":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Google.Android.Material":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Google.Dagger":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Google.ErrorProne.Annotations":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.JavaX.Inject":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Jetbrains.Annotations":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib":"1.0.0.0","Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib.Common":"1.0.0.0","ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core":"2.4.1.0","ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms":"2.4.1.0","ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android":"2.4.1.0","ZXingNetMobile":"2.4.1.0","iPay.BAL":"1.0.0.0","iPay.Models":"1.0.0.0","iPay.Services":"1.0.0.0","mscorlib":"2.0.5.0","zxing.portable":"0.16.2.0"},"nodestore_insert":1671087531.574328,"received":1671087530.695406,"sdk":{"name":"sentry.dotnet.xamarin-forms","version":"1.4.5","packages":[{"name":"nuget:sentry.dotnet","version":"3.23.1"},{"name":"sentry.dotnet.xamarin-forms","version":"1.4.5"}]},"timestamp":1671087529.619733,"title":"Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x2f (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{97112ae} (76e149fc-19ce-41a0-9...","type":"error","version":"7","location":null}

Here is the link for build logs https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dOUU9eXP2X3vm3mtSeJ3Ytm6HxTN4l03/view?usp=sharing

Please let me know if require more details

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  There is no useful full information in your post we could use to help you

Comment: @jason What information do you need?

Comment: The relevant code.  Logs.  Crash reports.  Exception details.  Stack traces.